# tensorflow map_fn with tensorflow gather inside not parallelizing

Tags: parallel-processing, tensorflow

The code I am writing is a bit odd, but rather simple, and I have reduced it to a basic dummy case where the issue pops op.

The gist of things is that I have a matrix where elements are actually indices to a second matrix, in this case nearest neighbors, with each row representing a single "query" and each column a neighbor. I need to grab the actual samples that these indices are pointing to, and put them into a 3D tensor (yes it is the intention for duplicates to show up if two "queries" share a neighbor.)

Example code with randomly generated values demonstrates the issue below.

```
randIndices = tf.random_uniform([1000,10],0,1000,dtype = tf.int32)
randSamples2= tf.random_uniform([1000,6],0,1)

output = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.gather(randSamples2,x),randIndices, dtype = tf.float32)
```

EDIT: I've rewritten my particular application to flatten the queries, use gather on that without a "loop", and then reshape the output back once the operation is done. Doing so for 100,000 "samples" and 10,000 groups of 10 indices takes about one millisecond, so this is no longer an issue for me, however I am still curious as to why it behaved as it did.

I profiled this using [tensorflow timelines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrWee.png) as such:

```
run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()

sess.run([output],options = run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)

tl = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
ctf = tl.generate_chrome_trace_format()

with open("dummyTimeline.json", 'w') as f:
    f.write(ctf)
```

This is what the profiler gives me.
[image: zoomed out screenshot of the profiler's view.]

A closer look at the jumbled mess. The operation should be parallelized but isn't.
[image]

Compare this to the results of doing the same profiling on matmul:

```
randSamples = tf.random_uniform([100,1000,1000],0,1)
randWeights = tf.random_uniform([1000,100],0,1)
output = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.matmul(x,randWeights), randSamples)
```

This is what I was aiming for with the gather function.
[image: What a matmul looks like when map_fn is applied to it.]

What's stopping tensorflow from parallelizing this operation? It doesn't seem that any two gather operations would need any knowledge about each other to function properly so it seems that this is one of those "embarassingly" parallel problems.